# ffmpeg - AVPixelFormat, what is "smaples" means in the documentation?

Tags: image, ffmpeg

I did not understand the documentation , for example:

```
AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P planar YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x1 Y samples)
```

I didn't understand the meaning of "(1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x1 Y samples) ",
and what does it mean 4:2:2 ? I could not find explanation anywhere.

Also , I see there are types like AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P  that have 12bpp. Does that mean that each pixel is represented by 12 bit ? if so, how is it represented ? Should I allocate two bytes for each pixel and ignore the last 4 bits ? or I should allocate something like ceil((#pixels)*1.5) bytes ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV ?

Answer (score 3):

> AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P planar YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x1
>   Y samples)

For all intents and purposes here, `Cb = U` and `Cr = v` (There is a distinction not being made here, but it will only make thing more confusing, So best to ignore for now)

The `P` in `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P` stands for planar. Meaning every channel has it own plane, or buffer. There is a separate image for Y, U, and V.

In `4:2:2` the chroma (`U` and `V`) planes are half the height of the luma( `Y` ) plane. so if your image is 1920x1080, The chroma plane are 1920x540.
For 4:2:0 The chrome planes are half height and half width, 960x540.

4:2:2 `16bpp = (8 × 1920 × 1080 + 8 × 1920 × 1080 + 8 × 960 × 540) / (1920 × 1080)`

4:2:0 `12bpp = (8 × 1920 × 1080 + 8 × 960 × 540 + 8 × 960 × 540) / (1920 × 1080)`

> Should I allocate two bytes for each pixel?

No, your should allocate 3 planes and fill them independently.

Comment: With 4:2:2 sampling, shouldn't the horizontal resolution be halved, with the full vertical resolution maintained? So that would make it 960x1080 chrome planes, rather than 1920x540, which halves the vertical resolution, but keeps full horizontal resolution.